# Unable to download TFS Plugin in Eclipse with "http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs" url

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install TFS plugin with "**[http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs**"](http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs**%22), its showing up couldn't find any software on this li[image]nk.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the website in a brower i mentioning that teh web appa is stopped. Th update doesn't seem to be available anymore.

I guess tfs was related to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/team-explorer-everywhere , thei indicate on their page to go directly to github an dinstall manually https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases